# Ошибка вTDictionary: Duplicates not allowed

Tags: delphi

Почему при одинаковых запросах **Pos(m[i], S) ** возникает ошибка в коде: **"Duplicates not allowed"**. Каким способом можно игнорировать эту ошибку: что бы если запросы одинаковые то - происходил поиск?

```
    dictYes := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create;
    dictNo := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create;

    while not Eof(Vhod) do
    begin
      ReadLn(Vhod, S);

      if dictYes.ContainsKey(S) then
      begin
        WriteLn(Vihod, S);
      end
      else if not dictNo.ContainsKey(S) then
      begin
   ............. запросы передаю из массива (m[i] := Memo1.Lines.Strings[i];)
         if Pos(m[i], S) > 0 then
        begin
          dictYes.Add(S, 1);
          WriteLn(Vihod, S);
        end
        else
        begin
          dictNo.Add(S, 1);
        end;    
      end;

    end;

    dictNo.Free;
    dictYes.Free;
```

Comment: @Igor, если имеете возможность посмотрите, использую Ваш - код.

Comment: Напрасно Вы убрали полный вариант кода. Теперь из вопроса совершенно невозможно понять, откуда взялось решение.

Comment: @Igor, Отредактирую и исправлю. Сделаю все по правилам.Хочу правильно все отредактировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var 
  ...
  found: boolean;
begin
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
    exit;

  ...  
  found := false;
  for i := Low(m) to High(m) do
  begin
    if Pos(m[i], S) > 0 then
    begin
      dictYes.Add(S, 1);
      WriteLn(Vihod, S);
      found := true;
      break; // здесь
    end
  end;
  if not found then
  begin
    dictNo.Add(S, 1);
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Заключаем `dictYes.Add(S, 1);` в блок `try .. except`. И при помощи `on e: EListError do` исключаем поиск одинаковых строк из списка. То есть, **если в Memo**, будет, к примеру - два, три... одинаковых слова для поиска, то при помощи такого метода будет осуществлен поиск только по первому (одному уникальному).

Отредактируйте ваш код вот так:

```
if Pos(m[i], S) > 0 then
begin
  try
    dictYes.Add(S, 1);
  except
    on e: EListError do
      WriteLn(Vihod, S);
  end;
end
```

Comment: @Денис Перед тем, как затыкать исключение `except`-ом, следует выяснить почему оно возникает. Я пока не вижу, каким образом эта ошибка может произойти.

Comment: @Денис Конечно. У меня все мнения - экспертные ). Я пока не понимаю, как мы вообще попадаем в этот блок, если строка `S` уже является одним из ключей в словаре.

Comment: @Igor, То есть получается что нужно вторую строку подключить то есть S2 или ? Но почему же когда слова разные то код отлично работает ?

Comment: @Денис Пора показать полный код ).

Comment: @Igor, Добавил код, посмотрите где ошибка ? (Код без правок там где если в Memo два одинаковых слова то возникает такая ошибка)